# The inferior stopped because it received an error from the operating system SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c++, qt

analysismainwindow.h

```
#ifndef ANALYSISMAINWINDOW_H
#define ANALYSISMAINWINDOW_H
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class analysisMainWindow;
}

class analysisMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit analysisMainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~analysisMainWindow();

private:
    Ui::analysisMainWindow *ui;
};





class chessboard : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setBoardImage(QString path);
    void setBoardSize();

private:
    int width;
    int height;
    Ui::analysisMainWindow *ui;
```

analysismainwindow.cpp

```
#include "analysismainwindow.h"
#include "ui_analysismainwindow.h"
void chessboard::setBoardImage(QString path)
{
    QPixmap boardImage(path);
    ui->labelChessboard->setPixmap(boardImage.scaled(height, width,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
};
void chessboard::setBoardSize()
{
    this->width = ui->labelChessboard->width();
    this->height = ui->labelChessboard->height();
}

analysisMainWindow::analysisMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::analysisMainWindow)
{


    ui->setupUi(this);

    chessboard board;
    board.setBoardSize();
    board.setBoardImage(":/images/images/horsey.png");

}

analysisMainWindow::~analysisMainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

This is the first time I try to make a Qt application and my code is probably not good in general as an approach. I thought I would make a class for a chessboard that would make it easier for me to create a chessboard and control the ui. I tried to nest it in analysisMainWindow class but that gave me a bunch of errors so I made it separate and the code compiled and ran but I got the error in the title. I did some research and people say it is related to pointers trying to access something in memory they are not allowed to. When I hover over the ui pointer the IDE shows 0x0, so it is a null pointer. Probably that is the problem but I don't know how to fix it and I have a feeling the approach is completely wrong and ui should not be used like that in your own class.

Comment: You are not setting `ui` for `chessboard board;`.

Comment: *When* do you "hover the ui pointer"? While editing the code? While in a debugger?

Comment: You do know that the `board` variable is local to the `analysisMainWindow` constructor, and that its life-time will end as soon as the `analysisMainWindow` constructor ends? It seems like you might need to spend some more time with a Qt tutorial, all widgets and UI object needs to be created *dynamically* using pointers and `new`. And you need to pass the "parent" widget when creating the new widget to enable automatic chained destruction.

Comment: I hovered over it while I was in a debugger but I don't know why, now it says 0x30, I get the same error nonetheless

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't know. How should I create it dynamically new chessboard board? How do I assign it to the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't initialize the `chessboard::ui` pointer variable it will have an *indeterminate* value, and using indeterminate values leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to initialize this pointer, by creating a `chessboard` constructor which takes it as an argument.

Also, for Qt to work properly you need to dynamically create UI elements, passing the "parent" UI element to it, similarly to what you're doing for the `analysisMainWindow` class and its constructor.

I suggest something like

```
chessboard::chessboard(analysisMainWindow* mainWindow, Ui::analysisMainWindow *ui)
    : QObject(mainWindow), ui(ui)
{
    // Can be empty
}
```

Then in your `analysisMainWindow` constructor you create the `chessboard` dynamically:

```
chessboard* board = new chessboard(this, ui);
board->setBoardSize();
board->setBoardImage(":/images/images/horsey.png");
```

Comment: did you write checcboard because I cannot use the name chessboard or is it a typo?

Comment: @Aggressive-Support35 Typo, sorry. :)

Comment: btw can I nest, or should I nest the class in the analysisMainWindow class? is that the more correct approach?

Comment: @Aggressive-Support35 That's more a question about personal preference. If you don't nest it, then it could be available externally for example in the UI editor of Qt, or from QML scripts, if you ever would want that.

Comment: The code runs fine and it works so thank you but now I get this warning `analysismainwindow.cpp:28:1: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'board' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]` Is it because I should delete it in the destructor?

Comment: @Aggressive-Support35 I know this is old, but yes: you need to release resources in the destructor, including your new `board` var